# error accessing model from view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

So bit too late in the project to be at this but i'm tidying up my project to try and refine a error I am receiving. Where I was using some of my model classes for many methods in my `HolidayCotroller`, So im trying to just run one method from one model.
renamed all the files and everything seems to be ok except for my `index` method

In my View for `Index` im using `@model HolidayBookingApp.Models.IndexModel`

but when i click on the below link in the UI:

```
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Holidays Remaining", "HolidaysRemaining")
</p>
```

the error states:

**The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'HolidayBookingApp.Models.IndexModel', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'HolidayBookingApp.Models.HolidaysRemainingModel'**

So I change the model to:

```
@model HolidayBookingApp.Models.HolidaysRemainingModel
```

but it is still giving me the same error msg.

So in my `IndexModel.cs` i created a new instance of the previous `HolidayremainingModel.cs`

```
HolidaysRemainingModel model = new HolidaysRemainingModel();
```

what now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this

```
@Html.ActionLink("Holidays Remaining", Model.model)
```

instead of your previous code

```
@Html.ActionLink("Holidays Remaining", "HolidaysRemaining")
```